# Prevent/Eliminate "Best Practice(s)" from Titles

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

#### Motivation

I have been seeing lots of *"best practices"* questions in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tags recently on my front page, some years old, out of date when they were written and people *answering* them with their opinions years later.

So I got curious and did a search and examined the first 50 questions of a couple of tags I am active in. I could not find a single one that was not full of opinion based discussion and rambling that was either worst practices when it was written or just plain misinformation from then and now.

#### Off-Topic for multiple reasons

[Why these are inherently poor questions is well documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354)

When you look at the answers you can see many are just **recommendations** questions in disguise at best. *Best Practices* is inherently opinion based and temporal even when there is consensus on a single opinion.

*Best Practices* questions worded where they fall afoul of the **spirit** of these `2` guidelines should be closed for any one/all the reasons above.

*Best Practices* change over time!
They are all off topic in one or more of the following reasons *asking for recommendations*, *too broad* and *opinion based*.

In almost every case there is no code either, that is another off topic strike.

#### Best Practices != Idiomatic

If a question with *Best Practices* in the title is actually about something more specific then the title needs to be changed. If it is about **idiomatic** code, that is probably on topic. *Best Practices* is at best, argumentative opinion. **Idiomatic** practices are empirical by ubiquitous consent by adoption and/or usually codified somewhere ( Python PEP 8 and 275 comes to mind ).

*Best Practices* questions implicitly are asking for **your favorite**. *Idiomatic* questions are asking for what makes something standard based on the published or agreed upon standard, which is an empirical answer that can be backed up with evidence. You *opinion* on whether the idiom is a *best practice* is an entirely different opinion based subject.

> An example is *accessor methods in Java Beans*, `getXXX/setXXX` methods are *idiomatic Java*. They are specified in the JavaBeans standard. Now if they are a *best practice* is arguable.

#### Straight from the "Don't Ask" page in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
> participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
> asking here.

Regardless of intent these questions also generate lots of discussion. So they are implicitly asking for discussion of everyone's opinions. They all devolve into a *you are wrong* argument between two opposing camps. *When most likely both sides are wrong, especially if I disagree with them both. `;-)`*

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
>
> your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
> answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Every *Best Practices* questions is a *"What's your favorite ____?"* question or it is an *"Whats idiomatic?"* question that needs the title changed.

Many show what the questioner is doing and asks falls afoul of the second guideline. *"Here is what I am doing, is this a best practice?"*

#### Migration

Some of these ***might*** be on topic at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) because they are about programming and are subjective but in scope there, but getting things migrated there is an act of futility in most cases.

#### Take Action

[Who wants to help edit/close/migrate these questions as appropriate?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20best%20practices) or at least edit *Best Practices* out of the titles and replace them with better titles?

At the least these are just *"tagging in the title"* and that should be discouraged if nothing else.

Some of the higher rated ones that just have a bad title are probably good [canonical-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canonical-answer) candidates.

And just to be clear, I used the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag as a strawman. If you are not active in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), please feel free to take a shot at cleaning up the tag that you *do* have relevant activity in.

###Feature Request

> We do not allow [best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) as a tag. I think we need to
> prevent it from being a title as well.

Comment: Trying to think of a counter example for a legitimate use of "best practices" in the title here on SO, but I can't think of any.  I can't come up with a title that absolutely needs those words without being too broad/opinion-based.  +1.

Comment: Only argument against this is that allowing it in the title makes it easier to find and fix/close these types of questions. (Often, the title isn't the only thing wrong with them.)

Comment: related: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)

Comment: The only counter example would be a question that can be modified to not ask for "best practices" and not change the intent.

Comment: Please don't.  I *like* it when I can tell that there is no point in looking at a question.  These ones yell "waste of my time" from fifty feet away.  Banning words in the title does absolutely nothing to prevent such questions from being asked anyway.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of outright blacklists for titles after the porblems we've had with them in the past: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161398/houston-we-have-a-porblem . I've also seen a number of questions asking for best practices when referring to a specific set of options for how to do something. These aren't too open-ended or opinion-based, and can have specific factual answers. I don't think all of these need to be closed.

Comment: 'best practices' is a welcome distraction from the more usual wars over religion, politics, sexuality and tabs/spaces.

Comment: @BradLarson Most questions that ask for the "best practice" to do something are either too broad or opinion-based. *If* a question that asks for a "best practice" is neither, then the term "best practice" is used vacuously and could be edited out without changing the meaning of the question (e.g. "What is the best practice to foo the bar?" could become "How do I foo the bar?") Or it has a specific meaning that the OP has obscured under the term "best practice". Again, it could be edited out in favor of an expression that reveals the specific meaning that the OP had in mind.

Comment: @HansPassant - that is what down votes and close votes are for, to tell you that things are not worth your time.

Comment: chances for this stuff to find home at Programmers are rather slim: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @pnuts - [excel best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+best+practice). Go for it!

Comment: @pnuts - editing the titles of these things can only be a *Good Thing™*

Comment: @pnuts oh god...

Comment: ['nuff said](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22best+practice%22+closed%3Ano)

Comment: @BradLarson So banning words in the title is not a best practice? ;)

Comment: @MartinJames and god forbid those that don't use emacs :P

Comment: Ok now you are dissing `emacs` that is crossing the line ! 

Answer (score 21):

#### Alternate Proposal

How about anything with *Best Practice(s)* in the title get a pop up warning that the words are most likely to get the question closed as off-topic with a link to the discussions on meta about it.

#### If they insist

Then the question gets shuffled off to the Triage queue and/or Low Quality queue immediately so it can be dealt with effectively and as rapidly as possible.

Comment: I remember that there is a warning about title with "best".

Comment: If we do go this way of trying to prevent anything resembling a question leading to even slightly-subjective answers, probably a similar thing ought to be done for any question which has *"should"* in the title. I still think this is a shame -- outside of specific domains like gaming, graphics, database, networking, etc. and just general language questions, they often boil down to what is correct/incorrect ("What's wrong with my code?"), what's idiomatic in languages that encourage a strong aesthetic like Python (again B&W correct/incorrect), and best practice (most interesting one to me).

Comment: This is not my opinion, this is the goal and specifically the [site *charter"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). **TL;DR** version *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."* and *avoid asking subjective questions where …

every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Very true, but I'm coming from the standpoint of a rebellious nature who thinks the encouraged questions are leading to a wasteland of troubleshooting debugging-service Qs. :-( At least that's the perception I get from my favorite tags. I love those somewhat chatty answers with anectodes -- ultimately best-practices, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design/1647679#1647679. I look at a homework Q next to it and don't think it benefits from a pro/enthusiast touch or the voting system that much (it's rewarding speedy answers)...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson ... the best practices one which draw on anecdotes and experiences is something which actually does seem to benefit from a genuine enthusiast or pro's touch -- it calls for experience rather than info we can simply extract from a google search, e.g. My favorite answers here often allow the answerer to cite himself.

Comment: @Ike - except when the persons anecdotes lead to an incorrect conclusion on their part or the part of an inexperienced reader. See also: [Dunning-Krueger Effect](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Dunning-Kruger_effect), thus one of the fundamental reasons **off-topic: opinion based** exists.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Very true -- but I have faith in the voting system to help mitigate that. The results I see of what gets up-voted in questions that don't reward the FGITW are encouraging -- not perfect but not bad at all. Mileage might vary here -- you might not see examples as nice as I do.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The Dunning-Krueger effect is an ever-persistent danger in this format, but I think it exists even for answers that boil down to black & white notions of correctness, unless people only voted on questions which they knew for sure themselves to be correct or incorrect.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The interesting qualities I notice in paxdiablo's posts (they're all rather chatty), is an extreme amount of open-mindedness. His kind of anecdotal nature is always accompanied by a disclaimer that there might exist a better way. It's the precise opposite of dogmatism, and dogmatism is often one of the quickest ways to ruin an otherwise decent Q&A on something which relates to best practices, like a design-related question. But I love his style of posts -- they bring personal experience to the table, and I find it a shame that they're now discouraged.

Answer (score 10):

I must admit, I love best practices questions! I love what they do for the site with people competing to try to find the answer that clicks with the most people. It's where the voting system and the competitive nature of answering starts doing something interesting with respect to community approval, a radical difference from some question which can be answered by the fastest gun in the west.

*Knowledge can be found by anyone knowing how to search for it. Experience cannot, it comes from personal practice.*

Hopefully without casting a negative meta effect, I want to direct attention to this answer from dear `paxdiablo`: [C state-machine design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design/1647679#1647679). It's a design question, definitely a subjective best-practices one, with an answer that rose to the top through a popularity vote. And pax's answer is filled with conjecture and anecdotes, it's far from a Spock-style dry technical precision answer. It's an answer that brings personal (and therefore subjective) experience to the table, it's an answer where the answerer is ultimately citing himself. And yet, isn't it wonderful? This is what I want from stackoverflow! I can do a Google search for many other things. I want to read the thoughts of experienced enthusiasts and pros about their experiences and what worked and didn't work so well for them. Isn't that one of the main things that experienced people can share -- what they personally (and therefore subjectively) found to work well in practice? Am I being too selfish? I've been coding for a very long time but I tend to see programming just as much of an art as it is a science, and that art side can't be so dry, so technical, that we can simply cite every answer and boil everything down to a simple SE metric. It is in those foggy cases where the popularity vote can actually help the most, to help navigate the art and design side of programming where there isn't a perfect black-and-white correct/incorrect distinction.

The highest-frequency question in the tag I often hang out in, [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), is this one: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), which is effectively a best practices question. It seems like a double-standard when these questions are so popular among the community and we refuse to close/delete them while discouraging such questions outright yet nevertheless linking to such questions all the time.

And it does boil down to opinion, but even those who disagree with the accepted answer there on casting malloc results, which is a firm "no", can still find some decent rationale for why the answerer believes that explicit casting here has more cons than pros. It's probably among the most commonly-linked questions within the C tag with the community as a whole telling new people that they shouldn't cast the result of malloc. To understand why not, see that question -- the community approves.

It is a popularity contest at the end of the day, but that's true of the voting system in general. It's put to good effect when it rewards some perceived sense of "quality" beyond the first person to get a correct, routine answer.

It's hard to fake experience with a best practices question. The background of the answerer tends to show through, and a good answer can be put in terms of pros and cons which aren't too subjective. Whether we agree with them or not, interesting dynamics occur there. An advanced developer often doesn't struggle with correctness the first time around writing code, they often struggle with maintenance of large-scale codebases, they struggle not to become confused by the complexities of their own creation. Best practices becomes increasingly more relevant and interesting and starts to take the spotlight with increasing experience. At the very least, it tends to provide more informative reading material than a troubleshooting question which boiled down to the person using `=` instead of `==`.

I would suggest going all the way to the opposite end, make it a tag! Then people know what they're getting themselves into when they click on a question with a `best-practices` tag. It might even have a tag description like:

> *All ye who enter, beware. This area contains subjective answers which may be out of date, hopefully backed by experience, but we make no guarantees.*

We already have a lot of tags which are often fronts for best practice questions, like [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/architecture), [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design), [coding-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style), and [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns). I love these tags since they often present questions which are more challenging to think about and respond to than your average *"What's wrong with this code?"* homework question.

Best practices is a very relevant topic in programming even if it's not considered suitable for this site due to its chaotic nature. If best practices aren't found here, they might be found in a book written by some random author, from a team's standards, from some archaic boss, or just completely from a personal source. Yet it seems like a shame to take these out of SO, as SO does something a whole lot better than these other potential sources. It subjects any writings about best practices immediately and directly to a community-wide review process. I can't think of a better format for such a topic than one which has this raw and direct exposure to a voting system. It's flawed, as best practices always will be, but it's considerably less flawed in this type of format (unless we completely distrust SO's community voting to favor good answers in general, for which I must then ask, *"what then is the point of a voting system and even SO in general if we don't trust the votes to align with good answers?"*).

With respect to the temporal nature of the answers, that's true but it's true of programming in general. Libraries and frameworks can become considered obsolete even more quickly than what is accepted to be a best practice. It's something to think about a lot, how this site is going to deal with outdated information in the future, but I think that's just a concern in general of just about anything except a language/hardware/OS/API-agnostic question about data structures and algorithms.

Comment: becoming obsolete is why **recommendations** are rightfully off-topic in addition to being opinion based as a secondary reason. These are just **recommendations** based on **opinion** even more so than frameworks and libraries recommendations.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Lemme just tell you how I see SO. I see it as mostly a tech support site for beginners who don't know how to use a debugger. Boring -- the 10,000th segfault from someone who doesn't know what a debugger is. Questions about best practices whether they are about how to effectively use a language feature or a design pattern are at least *interesting*. They at least invite answers which require some time and thought invested into them. I'm mainly desperate for interesting material -- and a best practices question seems like an oasis in contrast to an MCVE Q from one who doesn't...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson ... know what a debugger is while using a language as difficult and as dangerous as C or C++. It at least hits that pro/enthusiast exchange idea harder than "tech support" for people with homework.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson My fear is that as we keep expanding the range of OT questions on the site, all we end up being left with for the most part are those homework troubleshooting questions from students who haven't learned how to debug basic code yet -- SO -- the perfect tech support debugging service site for beginners.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The other part I'm seeing and getting bothered about is the very obvious double standard. We don't flag or close questions like that hottest and most frequently-active C question I linked to above on whether to cast the results of `malloc`. Instead it became, and remains, the most popular C question on the entire site. I think at the very least we have to be consistent here -- if such questions are to remain in the database, they'd best be marked as such -- ideally with a `best-practices` tag. Delete it or tag it properly is my thought, at the moment it's just disorganized.

Comment: there used to be a *"What is a debugger and how do I use it?"* dupe target in the [tag:java] tag anyway. I can't find it now, not even deleted version. Those clueless newbie questions are all one or more of the "What is a NPE", "How to compare Strings?" or "How to use a step debugger?". At this point, *all the interesting questions about any given tag have been asked dozens of times*, until a new version with new features comes out anyway. All this is pretty much off-topic from this specific suggestion about a specific indicator of crap questions.

Comment: That `C` question should be made a community wiki page and closed and locked for historical purpose. The current bounty to update all the answers as they are *out of date* reinforces that this type of question is bad. This should have been done 6 years ago when it was posted.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson With that C one, there were some answers which were out of date even at the time they were provided. :-D They're citing 25-year old C compilers giving warnings without the cast. But yeah, there are definitely interesting questions outside of best practices. I'm just up to my eyeballs in those newbie questions in tags like [tag:c] and [tag:c++] and I might see these best practices questions more favorably than usual because of it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It does get quite a bit blurry though, don't you think? When we discuss the benefits of mixins, it's blurry with best practices. When we discuss what's pythonique, the very idea of pythonique code is related to best practices. Any mention of a design pattern is immediately in the territory of best practices. So much of this mental model of how we write code and even the benefits that some programming language provide relate to perceived best practices. It's hard to divorce ourselves from it completely in favor of Spock-like technical precision.

Comment: Do not conflate *best practices* with *idiomatic*. There is a significant semantic different. For example *Pythonic* means *idiomatic Python* which is not really up for debate what falls under that term semantically. Design Patterns are debatable because they can be applied differently in different scenarios to varying degrees of appropriateness, thus debatable. Something that is *idiomatic* is not debatable, it has been settled.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That's true, though what gives rise to idiomatic code? At some point was a best-practices kind of question, drawing upon experiences of devs in the field, and even at the time a new programming language is born. It might be overly optimistic of the quality of the voting, the popularity of the site, and the ability to reach widespread consensus, but I could imagine some scenarios where SO could give rise to new idioms or cement effective practices already applied provided that it has the breathing room to do it. My perception might be skewed...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson ... I see best practices questions with very encouraging results in the areas I look at.. perhaps you see ones with more discouraging results.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I might also be biased as my primary language is C++. With C++, learning the language might take a year or so. Learning how to use it effectively might take 20 years and then some, never quite perfectly settled on how to use the language most effectively, always searching to do better. The knowledge there of how to use the language effectively is constantly evolving, with even the author of the language claiming there's more to it than we currently often think. To take out the best practices side there kills a great source of the constantly evolving knowledge of how to use it.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson Regarding outdated "best practices" - That is what the comment feature is for.  It does not matter if a question is related to "best practices" or not.  Answers eventually go obsolete.  Period.  (by the way, I +1'd this answer -- "best practice" questions are 95% of the reason I browse this site, just to correlate my own research with people that have field experience.)

Comment: How you see it and what the rules and charter of the community are diametrically opposed.

Comment: I would just like to say that there seems to be a huge disconnect between what you find interesting, and what is on-topic on Stack Overflow. While you may find subjective questions interesting, they are the exact opposite of the questions that Stack Overflow allows. I'm sorry but the whole of Stack Overflow is unlikely to change just to accommodate you.

Comment: @TinyGiant It might just be a matter of migrating more to programmers stackexchange. But I'm not sure about the "changing stackoverflow" part. Again, the most popular example in the [c] tag is a best practices question. We don't do anything about it. That makes it somewhat of a role model -- it's not like some obscure question from the past that people ignore now. It's among the most frequently-cited questions (people redirect others to it all the time). So therein lies the conflict -- it's like if these questions were shut down and removed as off-topic, I'd at least get a consistent message.

Comment: @TinyGiant As for the opinion-based part, even a close vote has the caveat about opinion-based not necessarily being OT. That's where I find one very experienced SO user saying this C question about malloc is not OT, while another does -- there isn't a consistent agreement there... but it is definitely a "best practices" question -- that is screaming out with the question, which begins with a "Should I [...]?".

Comment: We can basically take any meta post and say "there isn't consistent agreement there" because there are downvotes on the highly upvoted answer. If I see a question that asks for a "best" anything, and that cannot be edited out, I'm going to vote to close it. Simple as that.

Comment: @TinyGiant Is it purely the wording? I do agree that "best practices" in a title is obnoxious. Somehow it seems less so as a tag. I'm thinking of ones that fly under the radar, all the questions all over the site where the Q is basically asking what one should do in a situation. A tag there might be quite useful -- also it'd help you guys to identify potential suspects which might get received poorly and need to be shut down, the ones that are asking for way too much subjectivity and way too little expertise.

Comment: @TinyGiant Another way to look at it is if we put those questions most of us accept and consider pretty great like that most-cited C question about whether we should or shouldn't cast `malloc`, and tag them with `best-practices`, we would have an area which at least shows examples of what sort of best practices questions are acceptable, as well as what are clearly and obnoxiously OT.

Comment: "best practices" as a tag would be a meta tag. Think about it: when you ask a question, you're never going to be looking for the worst way to do it. It is implied that you want to know the "best" way to do something. The system determines what the "best" answer is through voting. If anything, "best" or "best practices" is superfluous noise that should be edited out. If it cannot be edited out and still be a question, it is off-topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant The thing that irks me there is the fuzziness without some means of organization. A tag like [tag:c] ends up getting *"Should I do this?"* questions which are totally mixed into the *"What is this?"* kind of questions. There's a radically different characteristic between those types of questions -- the former is calling for experienced answers, the latter is calling for knowledgeable ones (often found quickly in a google search). There's a big difference between, *"What data structure should I use for this situation?"* vs. *"What's the algorithmic complexity of an AVL insertion?"*

Comment: @TinyGiant A robot can answer the latter question and robotic types looking to share precise knowledge can seek those out. A very human answer is often required for the former one, and some might prefer to seek those out. At the moment the two end up getting muddled together all over the site, so I'm mainly looking at a desire to organize it -- make it less muddled. Basically I'm not looking at such organization as superfluous -- far from it.. even if `[best-practices]` might not be the right wording for such a tag.

Comment: @TinyGiant Wording-wise, English isn't my first language so I might just not be finding the ideal name for this imaginary tag. But I have this desire to make those *"Should?"* questions stand out more from the *"How?/What?"* questions. The majority of the site fits into the latter category, with *"how do I do this?"* and *"what's wrong with my code?"* types. But *"Should I [...]?"* questions are really interesting, especially for experienced users, since they tend to require information which cannot be found by searching Google, e.g. Also for those who have a distaste for them as strong [...]

Comment: @TinyGiant [...] as Jarrod here, they'd know quickly what kind of questions to skip over if we had an effective means of organization.

Comment: But, we categorize questions by what they contain, not by the type of question they are. The kind of tag is called a "Meta Tag" which is not allowed.

Comment: @TinyGiant I see. Maybe we just have a shortage of tags to accurately describe what these "Should?" questions contain. [tag:design] and [tag:architecture] and [tag:coding-style] can cover a lot -- maybe the malloc question might be suitable as [tag:coding-style]. I think there's a tag missing for those *"What data structure should I use?"*, since that's not design or architecture or coding style, it's about implementation concerns.

Comment: Most design / architecture / coding-style questions are actually better suited to prog.SE

Comment: @TinyGiant I think so -- also this `malloc` question. One difficulty I find is that most of the juicy stuff in those `"What should I do?"` categories are still here on SO, leaving programmers.se as kind of barren, mostly idle. I tend to wonder what would happen if we migrated that most popular C question which is ultimately best practices on SO to programmers -- help it gain some energy and momentum.. SO main site already has more than enough.

Comment: @TinyGiant This might merely be an issue with not enough best practices questions being migrated to `programmers.se`, especially the most popular ones, where they would be very clearly on-topic. If we started migrating a bunch of the most popular best practices questions on the site, including a whole bunch found in architecture/design to programmers.se, that might jump-start programmers, give it a lot of life, and people might start properly asking new questions there.

Comment: Migration isn't an option because it leaves a locked copy of the migrated question on the original site that can no longer be edited. So, we're stuck with what we have, until a new migration system is put in place.

Comment: @TinyGiant Darn! I've been trying to participate more in programmers.se but it's a pale shadow to main SO site, even for those "What should I do?" questions. Maybe just more aggressively directing new questions there might help... a lot of what I'm writing might become moot if programmers.se actually had as much going for it as main SO site in terms of those really popular "What should I do?" questions.

Comment: Keep in mind, prog.SE is ***extremely*** strict about the questions they receive, the golden days of "Not Programming Related" are long gone. They even have a bot in the programmers room that notifies them when users on Stack Overflow post a link anywhere referencing them so they can jump in and insta-deny the request.

Comment: @TinyGiant I've noticed -- it's hard not to find a Q which hasn't been closed there. I imagine some of that is due to the very low traffic -- same questions viewed over and over and over and dissected to death. It does seem more directly suited though for these types of questions which we might be tempted to label as "best practices".

Comment: @TinyGiant The kind of thing I'm imagining (hoping) is that a lot of the main site's energy for those "should?" questions end up on programmers.se, or ends up being categorized a bit more. I'd love to seek them out away from especially the "What's wrong with my code?" questions, and I imagine those really high-rep users who are bored might do the same. Mainly my desire is organization -- whether it's programmers.se or within the main site.

Comment: @TinyGiant If I go into my personal desires, it's to keep the experts on the site busy and even entertained. While there are esoteric "how/what?" questions which can't be easily answered by a google search, so many of the ones that exist currently fit that category. They don't need a veteran so much as someone who's good at searching and citing, a human encyclopedia. I mainly want to keep the veterans busy (myself included, but I'm not nearly as great as some of the experts on here like paxdiablo whose answers I want to read more).

Comment: I don't know the answer to that honestly. I'm pretty sure that is a question that everyone has in the back of their minds, and I'm sure SE will come up with a solution sometime between now and then. I'm guessing that is what the Documentation feature is going to be, at least when it first starts.

Comment: @TinyGiant That would be great! I might have a cynical view of the site at the moment just based on how many routine questions there are which can be answered routinely drowning out the more challenging ones. I'm mainly interested in ways to break up the routine, make the site reward experienced answers from genuine enthusiasts and professionals more and more. There are many ways to skin a cat -- I might just be tunnel-visioned.

Comment: @TinyGiant The only interest I have in "best practices" is that they definitely break up this kind of "fix my code, I need to turn it in tomorrow" routine. They can't be answered by FGITW's or the first person to do a google search or the first person who knows how to use a debugger that comes along. The entire appeal of that to me is just that it's one of the most prominent examples I can think of that rewards veteran answers besides esoteric knowledge questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant The ideal veteran Q&A to me is the one where the veteran can cite himself. It could be esoteric knowledge too -- like if Linus Torvalds joined the site, he could cite himself on a very esoteric question about the Linux kernel which interests him. But those can be quite rare in some tags/areas/subjects, unless the subject itself is esoteric. That leaves best practices types to me as the ones which attract veterans. I'm looking at it like, "How can this site engage Linus Torvalds?"

Comment: This is getting way out of hand, there is like four more answers worth of text in the comments here. We can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97696/discussion-between-tiny-giant-and-ike) if you like.

Answer (score -4):

I think there are definitely cases where a question with "Best Practice" in the title can be an appropriate question for SO.

Here are some examples:

- [What to put in a python module docstring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557110/what-to-put-in-a-python-module-docstring)
- [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

Though these questions don't have "Best Practice" in the title, they certainly could have and the questions would have essentially been the same.  Even good questions for SO don't always have just one correct answer.  But it's also possible for "Best Practice" questions to have just one or two correct answers, and not just be a mountain of varying opinions.

Searching the javascript "Best Practice" questions:

- [Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)
- [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

These could have just as easily been asked as **How to do function overloading in Javascript** or **How to encode a query string**.

So really, it's just semantics for some questions.  Questions that are truly just opinion questions will get closed as normal.  If it improves the question, we could edit the title of these questions to use a non-*Best Practices* title.

Comment: one persons *best practice* is another's *worst practice* in the other persons opinion if they do not understand why they are incorrect. Take the practice of marking as many things `final` as possible in Java. Lazy people and those that do not understand the benefits do not find it a *best practice*, the thing reusing a method argument redefining 40 times in a method is a *best practice* because it *saves resources* or so other mis-informed crap. If there is a valid question then the Title needs to edited to reflect that.

Comment: See how I improved [Best practice: escape, or encodeURI / encodeURIComponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) it is much more semantically correct to the intent of the question and the confustion the OP has about the various functions and it will make the question more valuable to future visitors because it will *hit* more often when people are searching for the same intent. No in depth knowledge of the tag is needed in such cases. There is no *good* use case that makes it not off-topic in some way.

Comment: if your argument that *its just semantics* infers that the difference is small and is intended to be dismissive it is incorrect. [*The phrase is misused when people intend to say only that the difference in position is very small. It is also misused when just trying to dismiss the other as not being worth the bother*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97603)

Comment: My main point of contention was the proposal to have an outright ban on "Best Practice" questions based on the title alone.  I don't think that is a good idea.  While some questions with "Best Practice" in the title are considered off-topic for SO, I don't see why they wouldn't be caught in the normal flag and review process, and why we would need to create a special case for them.  And while renaming some questions might make them more clear, I don't agree that categorically renaming all "Best Practice" questions makes them better.

Comment: @Brendan disallowing keywords that specifically make a question off-topic is, IMO, very much better than just expecting that every question asked in that format will be found and closed properly. For questions that aren't actually about best practices but rather how to do something, they would no longer be closed incorrectly; for questions blatantly asking for opinion based answers, they would be stopped before they even made it onto the site. I fail to see how that is not a win-win situation.

Comment: @TinyGiant Perhaps, but like I said, I don't think *Best Practice* is specifically off-topic, no more than *Should I be using spaces or tabs?* is specifically on-topic because it doesn't use *Best Practices* in the title.

Even if it was special-cased, it's not like those questions will disappear, people will just ask around the keyword ban.  Moderation won't change either, as reviewers and flaggers will *still need to actually read the question* first to decide whether it's on-topic or not.

Comment: @Brendan "Best Practices" questions *are* inherently off-topic as they are prone to attract purely opinion based answers and discussion, which is entirely against what Stack Overflow is about (Factual Answers to Questions). These questions are routinely closed using the reason "Primarily Opinion Based". I understand that you are a relatively new user here so you may not know this, but those questions *are* very off-topic Stack Overflow. Instead the user should ask an actual solvable question.

Comment: @TinyGiant If they are inherently off-topic, how do you explain the questions linked in my answer, which we all agree are on-topic?  Haha, I've been using SO for many years.

Comment: Those questions could exist very easily without the words "best practices" in them and be much less prone to opinion based answers and discussion. I'm sorry if my assumption based on your rep offended you, but because of your rep you cannot see the mass of crap deleted answers that these questions attract. From my previous argument: "*For questions that **aren't actually about best practices but rather how to do something**, they would no longer be closed incorrectly; for questions **blatantly asking for opinion based answers**, they would be stopped before they even made it onto the site."

Comment: @TinyGiant That's entirely possible.  It might just be that I don't see all the bad *Best Practice* questions because they are deleted before I ever see them.  So the only ones I generally experience are good, on-topic *Best Practice* questions.

Comment: @Brendan The point is that any of those questions that *are* on-topic aren't actually Best Practice questions. They are, at there core, "How do I do X" questions, which are on-topic. Which means that any of those questions which are good and on-topic are actually being brought down by the "Best Practices" phrase in the question because of all the spam and garbage those questions attract, which has to then be deleted by users curating the content. If those words were not in the question to begin with, those users would not have to expend nearly as much effort curating that content.